# Get latest tweet from user_timeline with twit npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter

I'm trying to create a discord bot with notification about new tweets.

I am using `T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow : ['798934987978510337'] });` for this, but it show mentions too.

Can I get only tweets from user with twit?

Comment: Reworded for grammar and capitalisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `statuses/filter` streaming API does contain retweets as well. You will need to filter out retweets in your own code if you do not want to pass them over to Discord.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me. Reference https://twittercommunity.com/t/only-receive-latest-tweet-from-specific-user-twit-npm/151478

```
var twitParams =
{
  exclude_replies: false,
  count: 1,
  screen_name: "your screen name excluding @"
}

T.get("statuses/user_timeline", twitParams, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data);
});
```